# How to crop PDF halfway and merge to a new file

Tags: pdf, merge, ghostscript, crop

I've got a PDF output file that has been generated by PowerPoint which has the slides on the left and lines for notes on the right side. The format is A4 and there are three slides per page. Now I'd like to print six slides per page without having the lines for notes on it (note: I don't have the PowerPoint-file).

I thought of cropping away half of the page and always merge two cropped pages to a complete one. I know, that this could be done using ghostscript but I don't have any clue how to do this.

Comment: in my opinion it would be simpler to do this with gimp scripting.  i don't have the code for you, but it's not a complicated thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

That can easily made with [pdfnup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfnup) and [pdfjoin](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfjoin)

Comment: How do you *crop* with pdf-*join* and pdf-*nup*?!?

Comment: @pipitas Using the `--trim` option. (see `pdfjoin --help` for example.)

Comment: Oh, thanx a bunch!